# Why Am I getting "Not All paths return a value" when using if inside a foreach

Tags: c#, if-statement, foreach, return-value, nested-loops

I'm trying to return a value once it finds the string match. I'm using the following code.

```
MetadataIcons mi = new MetadataIcons();
Type me = mi.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] pi = me.GetProperties();

foreach (var property in pi)
    if (property.Name.ToLower().Equals(prop.ToLower()))
        return property.GetValue(prop).ToString();
```

But, I get the error "Not all paths return a value" I thought I was able to do so that way. Do I really need to specific a return variable?

Comment: What do you expect your code to do if nothing matches?

Comment: On this method, just to return the value of the property.

Comment: But what if your `if` never matches?

Comment: @SLaks, Got it!

Comment: @VictorAChavez: SLak's point is that there are conditions under which nothing will be returned; i.e. if `pi` has no properties or if the `if` condition does not match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a function to have a return value in c#, you *must* return something of the same datatype or throw an exception. Your code lacks an "`else`" situation, so you're not returning anything.  If you want a default value, explicitly place it in your "`else`".  Otherwise, you may want to declare an `ApplicationException` and throw it (which counts as a return value in a way).

In your specific situation, it's better to declare a variable first, then use the loop to assign its value, then return that.  This skips the need for an `else` if you initialize it.

```
 string retval = string.Empty;
    foreach (var property in pi)
        if (property.Name.ToLower().Equals(prop.ToLower()))
            {
               retval = property.GetValue(prop).ToString();
               break; //stop looping
            }

    return retval;
```

You can also use ! to negate the `if` boolean result and do it this way:

```
    string retval = string.Empty;
        foreach (var property in pi)
        {
            if (!(property.Name.ToLower().Equals(prop.ToLower())))
                {
                   continue; //jump out of this iteration and go to the next                  
                }
            retval = property.GetValue(prop).ToString();              
        }
        return retval;
```

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @SLaks in the comments, there are theoretical scenarios where the code may not return any value.  It's possible that in practice those would never occur, but the compiler only knows what it sees, and it sees that possibility.

Scenarios:

- `pi` is an empty array, so we never enter the foreach loop.
- none of the `property` values has a name which equals the given `prop` value.

The below code returns the expected result if one is found.
However if either of the above scenarios occur, it continues to run (as it doesn't exit on the return statement) and so comes to the new line `throw new NotImplementedException`...; which causes an error to be thrown.

```
MetadataIcons mi = new MetadataIcons();
Type me = mi.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] pi = me.GetProperties();

foreach (var property in pi)
    if (property.Name.ToLower().Equals(prop.ToLower()))
        return property.GetValue(prop).ToString();
throw new NotImplementedException("I haven't yet decided what to do should this condition arise.");
```

Throwing an error is a valid action here (i.e. as if we error we have a different valid route to exit the function where we don't require a return value), so the compiler's now happy.
However, this may not be the behaviour you want (i.e. maybe you want to return a default value (e.g. `null`), or maybe you want to throw a different kind of error / perform some other action.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
MetadataIcons mi = new MetadataIcons();
Type me = mi.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] pi = me.GetProperties();
string somevalue = "";
foreach (var property in pi){
    if (property.Name.ToLower().Equals(prop.ToLower())){
        somevalue = property.GetValue(prop).ToString();}
}
return somevalue;
```

Comment: you have to add a `return` statement right after  `somevalue = property.GetValue(prop).ToString();` and have the loop stop at the first match